# Csv import error through smartercsv gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, smartercsv

I have this csv structure

```
"CATEGORY";"NAME";"AGE"
"Red";"John";"34"
```

When I import the file through smarter_csv gem I get this hash

```
{:"\"CATEGORY\""=>"\"Red\"", :"\"NAME\""=>"\"John\"", :"\"AGE\""=>"\"34\""}
```

The code I use is the following

```
options = {:col_sep => ";",:row_sep => :auto, :quote_char => "\x00"}
SmarterCSV.process(save_folder, options) do |array|
    Item.create(array.first)
end
```

What puzzles me is the \" that is added in each item of the hash. I have used this same method before without issues and I don't understand what is going wrong, but the expected hash should be plan text with no backslash and additional quotes.
As a note, is I don't use the ";quote_char => "\x00"" option I get a malformed csv error.

Answer (score 0):

This works out of the box, but the quote_char you chose was incorrect; it should be `'"'`, which is the default setting.

```
      require 'smarter_csv'
      SmarterCSV::VERSION
       => "1.2.3"

      data = SmarterCSV.process('/tmp/test.csv', {:col_sep => ";"})
       => [{:category=>"Red", :name=>"John", :age=>34}]

      # or like this:

      data = SmarterCSV.process('/tmp/test.csv', {
         :col_sep => ";",:row_sep => :auto, :quote_char => '"'
      })
       => [{:category=>"Red", :name=>"John", :age=>34}]
```